# Getting error, can not print the biblography

Tags: bibliographies

I am trying to make a template on the overleaf. I am getting this error.
[image]
You can see that the citation is not working, it is showing as a question mark.
Here is a view of my folder.
[image]
And here is what I wrote at the end of my main.tex

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{ref}
```

Here is what I wrote in Chapter 3,

```
\chapter{Simulation}
This is a test \cite{choudhary2006heterosis}
```

The error message is like this.
[image]

And this is in my ref.bib file.

```
@article{choudhary2006heterosis,
  title={HETEROSIS IN RELATION TO COMBINING ABILITY IN HYBRIDS BETWEEN MULTIVOLTINE AND BIVOLTINE BREEDS OF THE SILKWORM, BOMBYX MORI L.},
  author={CHOUDHARY, NAZIA and SINGH, AVINDRA},
  journal={Uttar Pradesh Journal of Zoology},
  pages={23--28},
  year={2006}
}
```

This is output.blg

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2022)
Capacity: max_strings=200000, hash_size=200000, hash_prime=170003
The top-level auxiliary file: output.aux
White space in argument---line 3 of file output.aux
 : \@input{Parts
 :               of the report/2_Declaration.aux}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
White space in argument---line 4 of file output.aux
 : \@input{Parts
 :               of the report/4_Theory.aux}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
White space in argument---line 5 of file output.aux
 : \@input{Parts
 :               of the report/5_Equipments.aux}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
White space in argument---line 6 of file output.aux
 : \@input{Parts
 :               of the report/6_Procedure.aux}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
White space in argument---line 7 of file output.aux
 : \@input{Parts
 :               of the report/7_Calculation.aux}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
White space in argument---line 8 of file output.aux
 : \@input{Parts
 :               of the report/8_Result.aux}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
White space in argument---line 9 of file output.aux
 : \@input{Parts
 :               of the report/9_Simulation.aux}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
White space in argument---line 10 of file output.aux
 : \@input{Parts
 :               of the report/10_Conclusion.aux}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
White space in argument---line 11 of file output.aux
 : \@input{Parts
 :               of the report/Appendix.aux}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
The style file: plain.bst
I found no \citation commands---while reading file output.aux
Database file #1: ref.bib
You've used 0 entries,
            2118 wiz_defined-function locations,
            496 strings with 3986 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 18 in all, are:
= -- 0
> -- 0
< -- 0
+ -- 0
- -- 0
* -- 2
:= -- 7
add.period$ -- 0
call.type$ -- 0
change.case$ -- 0
chr.to.int$ -- 0
cite$ -- 0
duplicate$ -- 0
empty$ -- 1
format.name$ -- 0
if$ -- 1
int.to.chr$ -- 0
int.to.str$ -- 0
missing$ -- 0
newline$ -- 3
num.names$ -- 0
pop$ -- 0
preamble$ -- 1
purify$ -- 0
quote$ -- 0
skip$ -- 1
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 0
swap$ -- 0
text.length$ -- 0
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 0
type$ -- 0
warning$ -- 0
while$ -- 0
width$ -- 0
write$ -- 2
(There were 10 error messages)
```

Comment: probably bibtex had an error in an earlier entry, use the overleaf menu to see the bibtex log (`.blg` file)

Comment: I can not find it. Where to find this ```.blg``` log file?

Comment: follow overleaf menu steps 1, 2, 3 [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BptX.png)

Comment: don't use spaces in file and folder names, as you can see that errors with bibtex.

Comment: Thanks, Ulrike, I thought it was a minor thing but it turned out to be a big problem. Removing spaces solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ulrike Fischer. She pointed out that I should have never used spaces in the folder or file names, as it was the culprit.